# "TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects" while saving Facebook Prophet model using pickle

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle, facebook-prophet

I am training a model  to predict energy consumption values using Facebook Prophet model.
But while saving model using pickle I am getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-9ef2990419d8> in <module>
      1 with open('forecast_model.pckl', 'wb') as fout:
----> 2     pickle.dump(model, fout)

TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

**Code :**

```
from fbprophet import Prophet
import pickle
model = Prophet()
model.fit(df)
with open('forecast_model.pkl', 'wb') as fout:   <== Error coming here
    pickle.dump(model, fout)
```

**df.head()**

```
                     ds   y
0   2018-12-19 15:00:02   250.0
1   2018-12-19 16:00:03   295.0
2   2018-12-19 18:00:02   288.0
3   2018-12-19 19:00:02   286.0
4   2018-12-19 20:00:02   229.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem.
I reinstalled fbprophet version 0.5, like

```
pip install -U fbprophet==0.5
```

if you don't need the latest version:0.6, you can try it.

Comment: found the issue in fbprophet github: https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1361

Comment: Thanks ! I tried with fbprophet 0.5 version but using that I got error :                   
                                                                                                           
" from holidays import WEEKEND, HolidayBase, easter, rd
ImportError: cannot import name 'easter' "
                                                                                                          
 while importing fbprophet

Comment: I used holidays==0.9.8, when I got the error about holidays.
I hope it becomes your workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The code given below worked for me:

```py
model = Prophet()
model.stan_backend.logger = None

with open('test.pickle', 'wb') as f:
   pickle.dump(m, f)
```

Link to solution: https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1361

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60483194/2) to the question ["TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects" while saving Facebook Prophet model using pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60483194/typeerror-cant-pickle-thread-rlock-objects-while-saving-facebook-prophet-mo) by the OP [Kanish Anand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10365777/kanish-anand) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>